# Запрет на отметку своего ответа лучшим

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

Очень интересует этот момент, зачем создана блокировка, которая ничего не решает?
Мне кажется, что раз пользователь дал уже ответ и смог сам разобраться (приложив информацию о том, как это сделал), то каков смысл ждать 2 дня?

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045235/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-ms-sql).
Тут уже не нужны дополнительные ответы, но, если они будут и окажутся лучшими, то всегда будет время отметить чужой вариант лучше. Так в чём же заключается смысл блокировки отметки своего ответа лучшим?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/339911

Comment: Но ведь это слегка бредом кажется. `Другие пользователю теряют шанс заработать очки`. Почему теряют, кто запретил отвечать? Неужели на сайте главным является погоня за поинтами, а не делать базу знаний больше и качественнее? Также интересно почему не хотят реализовать, чтобы была возможность сделать переголосование за лучший ответ, если тот же автор вопроса не посещает сайт, либо вообще один раз зашёл (критерии можно придумать по которым у обычных пользователей будет возможность голосовать за лучший ответ)

Comment: Если галочка стоит, желание добавлять новый ответ уменьшается. Запрещать конечно же никто не запрещает.

Comment: Поэтому и предлагаю сделать переголосование, его только продумать грамотно нужно.

Comment: Автоматика не может понять, действительно ли топикстартер решил свой вопрос. В поле ответ чего только не пишут: и уточнения вопроса, которые модераторы переносят в вопрос и частичное решение и приводят свой вариант ответа и просят ответить на оставшееся и пишут впопыхах решение, которое только кажется работающим, а потом либо укажут на это либо автор сам догадается. Вот на это всё и вполне разумно давать два дня. Пусть автор подумает, пусть другие посмотрят. Два дня - не две недели, вполне адекватный срок.

Comment: Переголосование надо предлагать на MSE на английском языке.